# Some explinations on the proof of a lemma from (Gamelin-Topology) book

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

In the following lemma, I need to understand why $g$ is continuous and where he used the property $|h(t)|\to \infty$ as $|t|\to \infty$.

My attempt: Let $h(t_n)\to h(t)$, then $g(h(t_n))=t_n-^?\to t=g(h(t))$. I'm not sure in which cases we can remove $(?)$.
[image]

Comment: Please provide some context regarding the question, how you encountered it, what you know about the concepts involved and where you got stuck trying to solve it.

Comment: I think, if $h$ is a uniformly continuous function, then $g$ is continuous.

Comment: @Alisad uniform-continuity of $h$ is neither necessary for $g$'s continuity nor sufficient for $g$'s existence.

Comment: @JonathanY. I edited the question

Comment: @kigen: He assumes that $g$ exists as a set map, so $h$ must be injective. Furthermore, $h$ is then a bijection $\Bbb R\to h[\Bbb R]$, which implies that $g:h[\Bbb R]\to\Bbb R$ is a bijection.

Comment: @kigen Thank you. You remind me to add $one-to-one$ in the question

Comment: @Ronald no problem. Now following up to Stefan H's comment: as functions, how are $g$ and $h$ related? And given this, what does it mean for $g$ to be continuous?

Comment: @JonathanY. I'm reading Lemma 10.7 pp.156 Introduction to topology by Gamelin and Greene. I want to understand where he used $|h(t_n)|\to \infty$ as $|t|\to \infty$.

Comment: Are you asking for sufficient conditions or also for necessary conditions?

Comment: Dear all; I added new stuff to the question, maybe it makes a change!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, the $|h(t)|\to\infty $ *as* $ |t|→∞$ information is essential. It tells you that for each $M>0$ there is a $N>0$ such that whenever $|t|>N$ then $|h_i(t)|>N$ for $i=1,2$. This means that the preimage of a bounded set $B\subset\Bbb R^2$ is bounded. Since the preimage of a closed set is closed due to continuity, you can follow that preimages of compact sets are compact, i.e. the map $h$ is a so-called *proper map*.
Now, a proper map $f:X\to Y$ into a locally compact Hausdorff space $Y$ is closed (Try to prove it yourself or ask me if you'd like to see a proof; it is only required that each point in $Y$ has a compact Hausdorff neighborhood). Since this applies to $h:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R^2$, we conclude that $h$ is a closed map. Therefore it is a closed embedding.

Comment: Thank you very much. I think I know how to prove the closedness part.